# I kept excel file in ondrive and shared to multiple users. Can we provide edit access user level based on data range

Tags: excel, sharepoint, automation

Col1-  Analystname
Col2 - managername
Col3 - Rating of analyst

Above is the fields and I want manager to provide input in col3 for their analyst only and should not see other managers input.

Answer (score 0):

Look at "Allow Edit Ranges".

After applying, protect the sheet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But I need to apply restriction based on manager name. If we go by range edit permission then when any data is added it wont act correctly. And we want to restrict view of other team details to any other manager. Please share your ideas on this.

Comment: @amalkumar With VBA one can hide whole rows and whole columns or entire sheets and give permissions to certain users through password or a certain Windows username.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Prema. But I tried that, and when we share file to edit in a common place lets say ondrive and share. Then vba would not work when they open the file. Hence users will see all records and edit anything unless they enabled the content. This is the reason I have not used vba to solve this. Any further suggestion would be great.

Comment: @amalkumar   One could split the data in different workbooks, share tem with particular users. For the person who may get access to all data, one joins all the data from the other workbooks. This is done with Power Query.

Comment: Thanks for sugestion again. But issue here is we have more than 60 users and data will be adding up monthly basis. And we cannot paste mnthly data on each worksheet 60 times. So need to keep a common file. That is obvious we can do it with power query. But only issue is to take input from multiple manager every month. Still I have not found a way to do this.

Comment: It seems you don't want or can't use Excel for this. Maybe try with an online spreadsheet then. You pay by user and can hide as much as you want. Can't remember that company for now which I have been using some time ago. You can Google it.